# Django - signals for two differents type of user

Tags: django

I have customuser model with two boolean type of user:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,12}$')
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17) 
    is_trainer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone']

    objects = UserManager(
```

And also two differents models with OneToOneField. The fields of any modells is not similar.

**Trainers models**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    ...
    *and more then 20 another fields*
    ...
```

**Client model:**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='client')
    ....
    ....
```

I want when new user is sign up, depending on which profile he chose (trainer ore client) in SignUpForm an appropriate model was created. 
For that I maked signal

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if sender.is_trainer:
            profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)            

        else:
            profile = Client.objects.create(user=instance)

        instance.profile.save()
```

But always created User + Trainers. How can I fixed it?

**Add my SignUpForm:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string('reg/acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/reg/success_signup/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'reg/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: sender is the class. instance is the record. You might want to do `if instance.is_trainer`. What is the role of `instance.profile.save()`?

Comment: check if instance.is_trainer:

Comment: If instance.is_trainer an error occured RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /reg/signup/
User has no profile.

Comment: `instance.profile.save()` is the line throwing that error. That line is not needed. It will throw error if is_trainer is not True

Comment: @Ramkishore, thanks it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    sender: sender model from which you'll receive signal from
    instance: model instance(record) which is saved (it will be instance of sender model)
    """
    if created:  # used to perform action only at creation time (avoid the code to execute during any update)
        if instance.is_trainer:  # access the field of instance
            profile = Profile.objects.create(user=instance) # you have correctly passed instance to foreign key and you just need to check condition for the same        

        else:
            profile = Client.objects.create(user=instance)

        # not necessary to call .save() here.. because when you used create method of profile or client object it is created and saved, as you haven't changed any field or value of instance you don't need to save instance
```

Comment: without save() everything worked! thanks for the explanation.